# Unit-Test for a switch statement on Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, switch-statement, angular-unit-test

I'm new to angular unit testing and I don't know how to test this switch:

```
  displayBadge(text: any) {
    switch (text) {
      case 'blabla':
        return 'badge badge-pill badge-success';
      case 'lalala':
        return 'badge badge-pill badge-secondary';
      case 'uuuu':
        return 'badge badge-pill badge-warning';
      case 'ooooo':
        return 'badge badge-pill badge-warning';
      case 'eeee':
        return 'badge badge-pill badge-warning';
      case 'zzzzz':
        return 'badge badge-pill badge-dark';
      case 'aaaaa':
        return 'badge badge-pill badge-dark';
      case 'qqqqq':
        return 'badge badge-pill badge-success';
      case 'ccccc':
        return 'badge badge-pill badge-warning';
      case 'rrrrr':
        return 'badge badge-pill badge-success';
      case 'ttttt':
        return 'badge badge-pill badge-warning';
      case 'fffff':
        return 'badge badge-pill badge-success';
      default:
        return '';
```

I'm using Simontest plugin on VSCODE and the code coverage always tells me I'm missing like 80% of the coverage, which is this switch.

I've tried this way on my spec.ts file:

```
it('text aaaaa', () => {
    component.text ='aaaaa'
    component.displayBadge(component.text);
    expect('badge badge-pill badge-secondary');
  });
```

but it doesn't work.

text is defined like this in my ts:

```
@Input()
  text!: any;
```

I've seen there are others posts about testing a switch, I've tried everything I've seen here on stack and in general on Google, but SimonTest always tells me this function is not tested.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to unit-test a `switch` statement: you're using TypeScript, so `tsc` will verify and _mathematically prove_ (in its internal, type-theory-only, _mini-theorem-provider_) things like `switch` statements. Also, probably very brittle too.

Comment: I wouldn't do this if it wasn't a requirement from one of my clients. I think the test should just verify if by putting in text the value "aaaaa" the switch returns the correct badge chosen for that input. It seems so simple, yet I can't find a way.

Comment: "I wouldn't do this if it wasn't a requirement from one of my clients" - in which case I hope you add an extra "_customer-has-incredibly-ill-informed-requirements-accomodation-fee_" to your invoice then, and tell them to read this: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/the-dangerous-myth-of-100-code-coverage-42d0e3ad83f3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since displayBadge() is returning the value you are testing for, something like this should work:

```
it('text aaaaa', () => {
 expect(component.displayBadge('aaaaa')).toEqual('badge badge-pill 
 badge-secondary');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Updateded the answer to remove some code. If that doesn't work, what are the errors you are seeing for the test?

Comment: when I visit test.html file (in the code coverage folder) it appears this: "function not covered" hovering on the name of the function, and "statement not covered" hovering on top of each return of each case.